# Correct helper method exception throwing

Tags: java, exception

I have functions like

```
class Chainable {
    public Chainable doStuff(String test) {
        return doSomething(test, true);
    }

    public Chainable doStuff(String test, String test2) {
        String toUse = test + test2;
        return doSomething(toUse, false);
    }

    private Chainable doSomething(String test, boolean version) {
        // do something
        if (somethingBadHappened) {
            throw SpecialException.generate();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

`SpecialException` is an exception the user is supposed to see. The message of the exception purposely contains the method that threw this exception. The user would call `doSomething("x")` and if it fails it would show `"Method 'doSomething' failed with the parameters: 'test = x | version = true'"`.

But the user doesn't care about the method `doSomething(String, boolean)` and its parameters. He used `doStuff(String)` and wants to see the message for that function.

So what I do is:

```
public Chainable doStuff(String test) {
    try {
        return doSomething(test, true);
    } catch (SpecialException e) {
        throw SpecialException.generate(e);
    }
}
```

which sets e as the cause of the new exception and correctly shows `"Method 'doStuff' failed with the parameters: 'test = x'"` (the user doesn't see the stacktrace, but if I need to debug I can see what exactly happened).

Now, it works, but I have to repeat myself every time I write a new function that delegates its work to helper functions. The problem is, I don't know how I should use a helper function for this, since the `SpecialException` finds the method name depending on where it is generated...

Is there another, better way to do this?

Comment: What's the e parameter for the second exception generation?

Comment: The cause for the exception. Same as if you would do `Exception cause = new Exception();` and then `throw new RuntimeException("message", cause);`

It's just for me if I need to debug so I know where the exception comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do: show the stack trace to the user. You can then use

```
throw new SpecialException();
```

without any concerns about what method will appear.

Comment: The user will use many different methods with different arguments, and they will (and should) fail often. Crawling through the stacktrace wastes time, he does not get shown his original arguments, which wastes time. That is why this information should go into the message.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, and as far as I know, this might be a nice situation to handle using [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) or AOP. In Java you can use [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) for that.

You would start by defining a ["pointcut"](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#pointcuts) - a specific moment in the execution of your code, for example a method invocation. Next, you would write an ["advice"](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#advice), something that needs to be done when the pointcut is hit. You put those two together in an ["aspect"](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#aspects) and have them [weaven](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/bytecode-concepts.html) into your bytecode during build.

In this case, you would need a pointcut that intercepts call to public methods on your `Chainable`, but the call should not be done from within `Chainable`:

```
pointcut publicChainableMethod()      :    target(Chainable)
                                        && call(public * *(..))
pointcut firstPublicChainableMethod() :    target(Chainable)
                                        && call(* *(..))
                                        && !cflowbelow(publicChainableMethod());
```

The first pointcut defines **any** call to a public method on `Chainable`, the second pointcut defines a call to a method within `Chainable`, **except** it should not be called while being in the control flow of the first pointcut.

Next to that, you would need an advice that generates the new `SpecialException` for you:

```
after() throwing (SpecialException e): firstPublicChainableMethod() {
    throw SpecialException.generate(e);
}
```

*Disclaimer:* I'm no AOP or AspectJ expert, so this approach might not work out-of-the-box.